# Can't access self-hosted site from LAN

Tags: domain-name-system

We've a site running on Centos (tomcat) server. It's ip is 10.10.0.60. Now I've setup a local DNS server so that we can access it from the internal network (say a workstation with ip 192.168.1.200) using the domain name. Somehow, i still can't access the site from this workstation. Doing a 'nslookup oursite.ca' from cmd line does resolve successfully to 10.10.0.60. The only way to access the site is by typing http://10.10.0.60. I want access by domain name to work as well. Based on the nslookup results, the dns seems to be working fine... so what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check the server logs on whether it does some sort of vhosting. Common webservers like Apache/lighttpd/etc. are regularly configured to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that nslookup does not use the system resolver, and so there may be some problem there. What error do you get from your web browser? Is it saying server not found, or something else?